# JSR223 sampler jmeter / Passing cookie data

Tags: ajax, jmeter, jsr223, cookiemanager

I am trying to simulate a parallel ajax requests using a JSR223 sampler, as mentioned here  https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter

But for my set of requests ,I am getting an `error,Invalid API/Auth Key`
I assume it is is becuase the authentication cookie is not being passed ,I tried to grab the cookie from the previous sampler using

```
HTTPSamplerProxy previousSampler = ctx.getPreviousSampler();
CookieManager cookieManager = previousSampler.getCookieManager();
HTTPSampleResult previousResult = (HTTPSampleResult)ctx.getPreviousResult();
log.info("Cookie Count is : "+ cookieManager.getCookieCount());
```

But I get the error

```
Cannot invoke method getCookieCount() on null object
```

,I do have the cookie manager enabled in my test plan.

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be great .

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means that there is no [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) associated with the sampler. You need to add it to your Test Plan and your code should start working as expected.

---

Be aware that as of now there is a much easier way to implement AJAX requests without having to do any coding, there is [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) which can be used to mimic AJAX calls by running its children in parallel. Just add it to your Test Plan and move HTTP Request samplers which represent AJAX calls under it. See [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) for more details if needed.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,I do have the cookie manager present in my test plan and the other samplers are able to use it to get the cookie data.

Comment: The parallel sampler worked for me,I was just trying to do the same thing using the JSR223 sampler .